# Where are the photos in Contacts stored on my MacBook (High Sierra)?

Tags: contacts

Pretty much what the title says. I'm trying to find a photo I have as a contact photo to use in another app. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use Finder and Go > Go to Folder... > (enter the following path)

```
~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/
```

From there navigate to the only subfolder (it should be a string of numbers and letters) and lastly, enter a folder called 'Images'. You'll see your contact image files in .jpeg format in this folder.

For reference the end path should be:

```
~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Sources/#######-###-###-########/Images/
```

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/Images
```